# Reciprocal -block in Simulink?

Tags: math-software, simulink

I have nonlinear-differential -system for water-flow. I need to find the reciprocal -block in Simulink. I could do it with reciprocal-sqrt -block and sum -block but too complicated, there must be some easier way of doing the reciprocal. How can I take the reciprocal in Simulink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Fcn block with 1/u(1) function.

Comment: How can I find it?

Comment: Use search :) The block looks like this: http://www.mathworks.se/help/simulink/slref/fcn.html